# Set referencing outlets programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a view with three rows and want to set referencing outlets for them programmatically - how is this done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'three rows'? Do these rows have a fixed class (`UIScrollView`, `UITextField`, etc.)?

Comment: yes, they are all custom uitableviewcells with class of CellWithTextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBOutlet` is just a marker so Interface Builder knows which instance variables are intended to be assigned objects from your nibs.  It doesn't really make sense to talk about assigning outlets automatically - their entire purpose is for the opposite approach.  The `IB` stands for Interface Builder.

If you want to assign objects in a nib to instance variables, you'll need to step over the view hierarchy and have some way of identifying the objects you want to collect.

You can step over the view hierarchy by accessing `self.view` in a view controller.  If there are objects in the nib that aren't subviews of the main view, you won't be able to access them.  You could load the nib with `UINib` instead of relying on the built-in functionality to get these objects.

You can identify the objects in several different ways depending on your needs.  You can assign integers to a view's `tag` property in Interface Builder.  You can look at the views that you know will be at a certain point in the hierarchy.  You can look at views of a particular type.  Or you can mix and match - for example, the `UIButton` subclass of the main view with an even tag.

If you are laying out your views with Interface Builder, it is almost always easiest to simply assign the views to outlets with Interface Builder instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
(any pointer) = [[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:(object's index)];
```

dont sure about Object's ID. try to find in identity inspector of interface builder

Comment: Technically not true... In your `-viewDidLoad`, you could loop through the subviews of your view and assign local variables to the ones you want (designated by class or some property they contain).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your table view cells of one view ordered from left to right you could do the following.

```
NSMutableArray *myCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NUMBER_OF_CELLS];
NSArray *allSubviews = [theView subviews];

for(NSView *aSub in allSubviews) {
    if([aSub isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCellViewClass class]]) {
        [myCells addObject:aSub];
    }
}

// Here you can sort your found cells with their origin's x values.
// -[NSMutableArray sortUsingFunction:context:] can help you with that.
// Do what you want to do
[myCells release];
```